# Why does DVD Player in OS X 10.5 "Leopard" exit full-screen mode during playback?

Tags: macos, dvd, fullscreen

When playing a full screen movie with the built-in DVD Player in OS X 10.5 "Leopard", not with Front Row, the movie will occasionally exit fullscreen mode automatically. No message box has popped up, so I don't know why this happens. Other running applications usually include Safari, Time Machine, and iPulse. Why does this happen, and what can I do to avoid it?